# Sharing material in Unity3d

Tags: optimization, rendering, unity-game-engine, shader, frame-rate

I have 12 materials in total in my game.Then I have various Gameobjects that have many materials attached to it for example Gameobject1 further have 10 Childrens each of which use 2 same Materials.Now with Gameobject1 I have 20 draw-calls I want to reduce them for which I turned on Dynamic Batching in unity3d and attached CombineChildren.js to GameObject1 but still the result is the same I have 20 drawcalls but I want to reduce it to 2 draw-calls because I am using only two materials repeatedly in Gameobject1 .Where I am going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are you talking about static or dynamic GameObjects?

Comment: dynamic Gameobjects.I am using a poolsystem to spwan the gameobject at one position then despawn them and then spawn them t some other point

Comment: Did you check that all the conditions in [Draw Call Batching](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html) like same size, lights, shadows,.. are met? If so, try out in editor player whether the number of draw calls is really depending on the number of children. Pause and set 5 of them inactive then look if draw calls decrease. To get realistic results you need to use the same quality settings like at your target player platform

Comment: I played the game the pause it and remove 1 material from each of the 10 children of gameobject one and then played the game and still the draw calls were 20

Comment: I am still waiting for answer apart from this can someone tell me if there is any GameObject have X number of Children and each X have 2 same materials how to share those materials among the all X children

Comment: Ok, some of the meshes child Gameobjects are using more than 900 vertices .And in drawcall batching link mentioned above it says the meshes vertices should be less 900.Is this the reason the Gameobjects are not batched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was able to solve this problem by combining all the meshes of the childs game objects to a single mesh with a **CombineMeshUtility.js** that comes with unity3D. So the parent game object(Empty Gameobject) now has 1 game object that is the mesh of all the childs and then it has other child game objects without any renderer or material. I hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

(1) Use Occlusion to only render what your camera in the scene is viewing .
occlusion is a very efficient way of reducing draw calls.

[Occlusion Culling](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html)

(2) Use the same materials for objects .

(3) you can Lightmap your scene.
then use this tool to to compress all the lightmaps into one large map .
[Tool found here in detailed explanation](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/36036/how-can-i-increase-the-texture-size-of-the-lightma.html)

[Scene Optimization](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_ECHyKN55E)

if you use all three methods , your draw calls will be drastically reduced without compromising graphics quality of functionality